# Где найти примеры использования кодека H264 Cisco для андроид

Tags: java, android, kotlin, cisco, rtp

Мне нужно декодировать видеопоток H264, но стандартный MediaCodec не справляется. Нужен пример использования H264 Cisco в андроиде

Comment: Стандартный MediaCodec декодирует на GPU, если он не справляется, вряд ли cisco справится.

Comment: знаю проекты, где он используется, так вот он как раз-таки справляется, но они закрытые, нужен пример использования